# how to get protocol from ip and port with Python3?

Tags: python, ip, protocols, ports

i need get protocol(HTTP, FTP, SSMTP, IMAP, ETC) from ip address and port with Python3.

**Example:**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
protocol = s.connect( ("localhost", 80 )
print protocol #print HTTP
```

Comment: The IP address doesn't play. You can get the protocol name with the system call `getprotobytnumber()`. It's not in the standard libraries, but it looks like you could use https://bitbucket.org/maze/getent/src/408aef1743dc/getent/libc.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it's not possible to detect the protocol type of a server listening on some port.  The best you can get is request the name of the service that is normally associated with some port number:

```
>>> socket.getservbyport(80)
'www'
```

Comment: @Olaf: Define "Safe".  What's the problem you are actually trying to solve?